# Sliding two UIViews left/right with animation is not precise

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a problem with animating two UIViews left/right. It's basically a push/pop style animation. The problem is that from time to time, they don't stick together and the background color (vertical line) is visible between them. That doesn't happen everytime but it's annoying and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
This only happens on the actual device. On the iOS Simulator (regular or retina) the vertical line is not visible at any time and the animation is very precise.

Heres my code in short:

```
UITableView *table1 = ...
UITableView *table2 = ...
table1.center = onScreenCenter; // This is the center of the screen
table2.center = leftOffScreenCenter; // This is the on screen center - width of the table2
CGPoint rightOffScreenCenter = ... // The right offscreen

[UIView animateWithDuration:kSearchBarAnimationDuration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         table1.center = rightOffScreenCenter;
                         table2.center = onScreenCenter;
                     } completion:nil];
```

Comment: I would try to set coordinates after animation is done in completion block, also CGPoint coordinates are float, maybe, just in case, it is better to make them integers in the end. Just thoughts...

Comment: Have you tried to look to the onScreenCenter, leftOffScreenCenter etc. values to see if they are always the same? And do the distances between start and end points for each views are the same? Because you're using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` so maybe one of the view starts to slow down before the other. You should also look if the variables values are rounded or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've set the coordinates in the completion block and rounded the floats (only Y coordinates were float numbers) and it's still happening. I also checked the distances with NSLog and they're the same everytime - each tableview is traveling at 262px.
Is there something special about `UITableviews`?